# QT or GTK for an embedded real-time display system based on Linux

Tags: qt, graphics, gtk

We are trying to develop a real-time display system in safety critical domain. (All this is at very basic stage.) One option I have is to write my own Widgets using OpenGL. Other two options is to use something like GTK or QT.

QT seems easy to use and has good development tools. But I have worked on several applications in real-time domain using GTK but none in QT.

Can anyone point out to me the trade-offs involved here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am settling with direct OpenGL programming for now.